# Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: php, php-7

Please help, the error is something like this :

> Warning: Undefined array key "Nama" in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\phpdasar\pertemuan7\latihan2.php on line 11
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "NIM" in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\phpdasar\pertemuan7\latihan2.php on line 12
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "Email" in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\phpdasar\pertemuan7\latihan2.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "Jurusan" in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\phpdasar\pertemuan7\latihan2.php on line 1

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="img/<?= $_GET ["gambar"]; ?>"></li>
    <li><?= $_GET["Nama"];?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I have to mention, that what you are doing there is dangerous because it can cause [reflected XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

That out of the way, you have to check if the index of the `$_GET` array is defined.

```
<ul>
    <li><?= isset($_GET["Nama"]) ? $_GET["Nama"] : "";?></li>
</ul>
```

As requested in the comments, here are some ways, you could prevent XSS for this example:

```
htmlentities($_GET["Nama"]);
// or
filter_var($_GET["Nama"], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

both effectively do the same and lead to browser just outputs what the user entered or provided in the URL without interpreting any of it (check [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) for filtering and sanitizing inputs)

Comment: jumper85, thank you for helping

but what is XSS? I'm sorry but I'm very new to programming so I don't understand a lot of things.

Comment: @DewiSari - It's all explained in the link "reflected XSS attacks" they posted with the answer.

Comment: it's short for cross-site scripting, someone could set malicious code (usually some javascript) in your sites URL and it gets reflected because you print it without any filtering/sanitizing. [Here](https://dev.to/anastasionico/good-practices-how-to-sanitize-validate-and-escape-in-php-3-methods-139b) is an article that explains some of this.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Show how to protect against XSS while you're at it, since it was an important and good point you made regarding it :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you're right, added some examples

Comment: @MattDMo 
Thank you for the advice. I have done it.